# Version control conventions and best practice

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I currently use SVN for my projects (though I will be trying git out soon) and I know most of the basics (committing, updating, branching, merging etc) though I feel I'm still a bit ignorant on how to properly use it. By the way, my projects only currently involve myself.

Heres an example scenario: we have the SVN server, the live web server, the dev/test web server and my workstation. I create a new feature involving multiple new files and commit it with the message "created new feature X", once checked out on the dev server I go through the cycle of seeing an error, fixing the error, committing, checking out, repeat until all the errors are gone. Some of those error fixes may have been simple typos.

So I'm slightly confused because the main feature commit seems to be "on par" with the tiny typo fixing commits (if that makes sense), when I see a list of versions I probably just want to see the main changes and not minor fixes. Also, the "meaningful commit message" may take 10 times longer to type out then the actual error fix so more often then not I just leave it blank or type "er". This doesn't seem quite right. So what am I missing? Or am I just being lazy?

Answer (score 2):

In all version control systems, commits / revisions are equal and have no importance assigned to them based on the magnitude of the change. This is where branching and tagging come into picture. Tag a "functionally complete" set of commits since the previous tag / on the branch and work on that in test / web server. ( Also, can I suggest automated testing and continuous integration.)

Meaningful commit messages are part and parcel of version control. Irrespective of how small your change is, try making the message meaningful. I many development teams, the commit message is fixed to be in a fixed format and have some necessary information like bug tracker number etc. Even for a small project with just one person, for now, it is always good to provide proper messages. In Git, you can easily edit the commit messages if you want, at a later stage and then push to the central repo. This way, you can give smaller messages ( note that I am not saying small messages need not be meaningful) while committing and then spend some time in "fine tuning" your history.

Answer (score 2):

A surprisingly good book on best practices is [Practical Perforce](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101855.do). It is a book about a proprietary version control system called Perforce, but the book goes on to explain the best way to use Perforce which ends up being the best way to use almost any version control system.

I've learned a lot of best practices from this book which I've applied to other version control systems, and I've recommended it to other people -- even if they never plan on using Perforce -- just because it has some excellent best practices ideas. These include:

- Don't use environment based branching (i.e. a special `UAT` branch because what's in Development will eventually end up in UAT).
- Branch when required, and not before. This mainly means that you branch for a release when the release is *code complete* and new stuff that isn't in the release will be put in the code.
- Release off of branches and not the trunk. This will allow you to do hotfixes while still working on the next release.
- Don't try to pick and choose fixes. It never works as expected. There will always be a code change that depends upon another code change that depends upon another code change that you don't want to release.
- Using a continuous integration system that can do automated testing and building on each change.

I know it seems strange to read a book about one version control system when you want to use another, but most version control books are about the nuts and bolts of the software and not the best practices on using that software. This is one of the few books that covers both, and much of it can be applied to other version control systems too.

Comment: Does "Branch when required, and not before" apply to git?  The common wisdom seems to be that git handles branching and merging very well, and that branching early and often is good practice.

Comment: @KeithThompson - It's not a matter of how well _merging works_. Branching and merging are pains no matter how wonderful the software is. The big problem is tracking your branches, issues, and merging and conflict resolution. If you use a continuous build system, each branch needs a build. Therefore, the less branching, the easier it is to manage your project. That doesn't mean _don't branch_, it means don't create elaborate branching hierarchies that managers love making into PowerPoint slides.

Comment: The CVS manual contains one of the best general tips about version control ever right at the beginning, imho: "[A version control system] is not a replacement for communication"